# Changing keyboard type using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an application build on angular js.
It is an hybrid application.

I would like to change the type of keyboard from "tel" to "text" dynamically, i.e. i have an input filed which accepts postcode in "1234AB" format. After typing "1234", i want the keyboard to switch to text.

Is that possible using javascript?

I did change the type of input field from `tel` to `type`, however i ran into the problem tat when type was changed, the keyboard is dismissed automatically. I again have to tap of focus on the textbox to bring the keyboard up.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Everything is possible, but show us what you've tried and we'll tell you what you did wrong if you're not able to do it. But asking if it's possible or asking someone to write the code for you is not how SO works.

Comment: You could change the input type from the one type to the other and hope that the OS does switch the layout. If not you might test to blur and refocus that element again.

Comment: if numbers is fixed ( like 4 symbols of 'tel' and then user can type 'text' ) you can switch input to "text" after the user is riched the limit by using `length`

Comment: Sorry i missed to add the code i tried: I did change the type of input field from tel to type, however i ran into the problem tat when type was changed, the keyboard is dismissed automatically. I again have to tap of focus on the textbox to bring the keyboard up.

Comment: @PrenithT add relevant information to the question and not as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below to change the type once the input's length has reached 4.

If that doesn't trigger a keyboard change yet, try to blur and refocus the input within the `if`.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
    e.target.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    e.target.blur();
    e.target.focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="number" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried almost eh same thing. I cannot blur after 4 digits because i have added validations in blur, which will show an error message stating the postcode is incorrect. Basically i wanted the keyboard to switch without the need to refocus.

Comment: Then please ask the question you have the next time, not something that isn't the real question... @PrenithT

Comment: better `if (e.target.value.length === 4) {`